# Listing explicitly defined methods only (Reference Classes)

Tags: r, oop, methods, reference-class

Is there a way to list only those methods of a Reference Class, that were **explicitly** defined in the class definition (as opposed to those methods inherited by "system classes" such as `refObjectGenerator` or `envRefClass`)?

```
Example <- setRefClass(
    Class="Example",
    fields=list(
    ),
    methods=list(
        testMethodA=function() {
            "Test method A"
        },
        testMethodB=function() {
            "Test method B"
        }
    )
)
```

What you currently get by calling the `$methods()` method (see `?setRefClass`):

```
> Example$methods()
 [1] "callSuper"    "copy"         "export"       "field"        "getClass"    
 [6] "getRefClass"  "import"       "initFields"   "show"         "testMethodA" 
[11] "testMethodB"  "trace"        "untrace"      "usingMethods"
```

What I'm looking for:

```
> Example$methods()
 [1] "testMethodA" "testMethodB"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Try this:

```
> Dummy <- setRefClass(Class = "dummy")
> setdiff(Example$methods(), Dummy$methods())
[1] "testMethodA" "testMethodB"
```

**2)** Here is a second approach which seems to work here but you might want to test it out more:

```
names(Filter(function(x) attr(x, "refClassName") == Example$className, 
    as.list(Example$def@refMethods)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that's my current workaround as well. But I wondered if there's something more build-in as I don't like the idea of having a dummy class just for the sake of an explicit comparison.

Comment: I have added a second approach.

Comment: Wow, some awesome `Filter` kung fu there! :-) Never used that function before, but seems very powerful! Thanks man.

Comment: I just don't completely get `Filter` yet: what's `f` actually applied to, i.e. what's the `x` when calling `f` inside of `Filter`? The result will give me a position index that's used to index the second arg of `Filter`, i.e. the vector of method names, right? Is there a way to see the result of executing `f` seperately?

Comment: `Filter` applies the function to each component of the list and then returns those components for which the function result was `TRUE`.

Comment: Ah, okay got it! I was looking for those `refClassName` attributes in `attributes(getClass("Example"))` etc. and couldn't find it. But actually pretty obvious that it must be somewhere in `x` of `Filter` (`names(attributes(as.list(Example$def@refMethods)[[1]]))`) ;-) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

No, because the methods in a reference class "inherited" from the parent are actually copied into the class when it is generated.

```
setRefClass("Example", methods = list(
  a = function() {}, 
  b = function() {}
))

class <- getClass("Example")
ls(class@refMethods)
#> [1]  "a"            "b"            "callSuper"    "copy"         "export"      
#> [6]  "field"        "getClass"     "getRefClass"  "import"       "initFields"  
#> [11] "show"         "trace"        "untrace"      "usingMethods"
```

But you can find out the method also defined in the parent and return those:

```
parent <- getClass(class@refSuperClasses)
ls(parent@refMethods)
#> [1]  "callSuper"    "copy"         "export"       "field"        "getClass"    
#> [6]  "getRefClass"  "import"       "initFields"   "show"         "trace"       
#> [11] "untrace"      "usingMethods"
```

(note that I'm ignoring the possibility that your class has multiple parents, but that would be easy to generalise)

And then use `setdiff()` to find the difference

```
setdiff(ls(class@refMethods), ls(parent@refMethods))
#> [1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Read your answer prior to Gabor's update and thus thought his answer should "fail" as `Example$def@refMethods` looks a lot like `class@refMethods`. But seems like filtering the actual attribute entries for the respectiv class name (`Filter()`) does the trick!